# Push Notifications from web server (running in android device) to Android Client app in a Closed Network

Tags: android, rest, websocket, push-notification, message-queue

I am working on a system, that has One server (Android Device) and 3 types of Android Clients (It can have several clients of the 3 types). 
The entire system should be in a closed network with only WiFi and no internet.

The following things are installed on Android device which acts as a server.
1. I have a webserver (KSWEB) with PHP scripts
2. MySQL (part of KSWEB) as a database

I would like to know the architecture for the same.

1. To communicate the client and server (Currently it is done using KSWeb, and JSON webservices)
2. Data push from the Android server to app running in Android clients. 
   For Eg. whenever there is a change in the data in the database, Server must send the push notitification to the android app running in android client device with out using GCM as I do not have internet. Is there any PUSH services available to push the data from the server (running in android) to the client app?
3. Mechanism to avoid data loss when using the webservices

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using Parse? This can all be done relatively easily with that.

https://www.parse.com

And here's the getting started doc: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider using polling mechanism from the client devices